# Fixed header with variable height

Tags: css

I have a header with 60px height when document width is greater than 760px. So, the body is show just below the header and no problem, but when width become smaller, the height it's two lines (120px) so the body is partially hidden at the top.

How can I solve this?

Here is the code I use:

```
.main_header {
    width:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index:100;
}
.main_body {
    margin:70px auto;
}
```

Note: The page is responsive.

Comment: Change the .main-body` margin in a media query?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the margin of `.main-body` first to be 120px, which will apply to all window sizes.  Then you can override the margin at a specific width using a media query.  Note: with the CSS shorthand you are using, the `main-body` top and bottom margins will be affected.

```
<style>
.main_body {
    margin:120px auto;
}

@media(min-width: 761px){
    .main_body {
        margin:70px auto;
    }
}
</style>
```

Media Query Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries